# Notifications for Outlook Web Access

Tags: office-365, outlook-on-the-web

My organization asked us to support a limited Microsoft Office license that only allows access to portal web applications, such as Excel, Office, and Outlook online. The only inconvenience is that Outlook does not notify the user when a new email is in the inbox. My end-user expects a sort of number to appear on the tab similar to what Facebook provides.

I tried looking at the Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer options but could not find a third-party application I felt comfortable installing onto a client's computer.

Is there an obvious notification solution that doesn't require the installation of third-party "free" extensions on a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your settings by clicking the gear at the top right. There's an option for Mail under Your app settings on the right-hand column that will appear. Click that link. Options column will open on the left side of the page. Go to Message options. Sound and notification options are there.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be native HTML5 desktop notifications working for Outlook web now, but only under Windows. It's not there for Linux, which is really strange given it's the same API. Not sure why they chose not to support it under Linux given that's really the only missing piece for critical feature parity in the browser.

Comment: I got it to work on Linux with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg on Windows Firefox mode (I now see the Desktop Notifications option in the settings).

Comment: Hey @billy, I don't use Chrome, and the your setup works validates my assumption that they don't need to do anything to support it, they're actively disabling it.